# Extra semicolon at end of value when string contains ampersand sign

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeginiter and I'm seeing a semicolon added to the end of my string when using an ampersand sign. See below. BTW, I'm storing the value into a MySQL DB.

I am using `htmlspecialchars` before I insert the value into the DB.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('item_name','description','trim|required|min_length[3]|xss_clean');
```

This works:

```
$string = "you & I";
// Displays "you & i"
```

This appends a semicolon in DB:

```
$string = "you&i";   
// Displays "you&i;"
```

Comment: HTML escaping belongs into the output logic. (While better-safe-than-sorry and doing it prematurely isn't wrong per se, it's not the recommended approach. Albeit the issue here was just an overzealous implementation.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're making use of the `xss_clean` "feature" of CI which is just broken. Don't expect your data to survive if you apply `xss_clean` somewhere.

Instead, disable it and things should be fine.

Then filter your data appropriately. The suggestion to actually use `xss_clean` is just misleading in the CodeIgniter documentation. Take care.

Comment: woah, that did it. I removed `xss_clean` and it works. Should I be using something else in its place?

Comment: The fact that you ask is a clear sign that you don't know what you actually did. If you want to securely code your application, you must first learn the basics of input, output and encoding. So what can you do instead? Filter appropriately, that is by knowledge, not guess.

Comment: I meant if there was another builtin CI function. I'll filter using some of the standard PHP function.

Comment: Yes go with the standard [PHP filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php), they work much more specifically so you can find something for the job to do. Avoid CI's build-in functions for anything security related.

Comment: Thx hakre, I never knew about the filter functions. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the `&i` is interpreted as entity. I suggest you to convert all the html special chars (as `&`, `<`, `>` and so on) with their respective [htmlentities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). In php you can do this using [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) functions.

Comment: so use `htmlentities` instead?

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I google and nothing came up. Guess `xss_clean` was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Before you to save data into database, the POST data has already been contaminated.

By the way I am using the CI framework too.

Example, Client Side post data
  `Cow&Gate/英国牛栏`
using normal form post method, and what you would get in PHP Server Side?

You would get
  `Cow&Gate;/英国牛栏`
Oddly, a semicolon has been added

If you are posting data with XML(or ajax or jquery), you can use the `encodeURIComponent` method in javascript to encode the data before you post it to server, and you would't need to do any extra work at the PHP Server Side.

Like this:
`$.post('http-server-API', {"field": encodeURIComponent('Cow&Gate/英国牛栏')})`

Check the $_POST params in PHP Server Side (no semicolon would been added)
[image]